# Split unpredictable length comma separated field not taking first record in series

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am running some code to split a slash-separated field into multiple rows, but the first value in the series is not carrying over. Does anyone know what I'm missing. Also, Rows that only have one record are not carrying over.

```
Public Sub ReformatTable()

Dim db          As DAO.Database
Dim rs          As DAO.Recordset
Dim rsADD       As DAO.Recordset

Dim strSQL      As String
Dim strMPG, strBusinessName, strCustomerNumber, strCustomerName, strCountStartDate, strCCStatus   As String
Dim strSplitMPG   As String
Dim varData     As Variant
Dim i           As Integer

Set db = CurrentDb

' Select all eligible fields (have a comma) and unprocessed (SPLIT_MPG is Null)
strSQL = "SELECT BUSINESS_NAME, CUSTOMER_NUMBER, CUSTOMER_NAME, COUNT_START_DATE, CC_STATUS, MPG, SPLIT_MPG FROM [tmStarCycleCountStatuses_SlashesforCommas] WHERE ([MPG] Like ""*/*"") AND ([SPLIT_MPG] Is Null)"

Set rsADD = db.OpenRecordset("tmStarCycleCountStatuses_SlashesforCommas", dbOpenDynaset, dbAppendOnly)

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)
With rs
    While Not .EOF
        strMPG = !MPG
        strBusinessName = !BUSINESS_NAME
        strCustomerNumber = !CUSTOMER_NUMBER
        strCustomerName = !CUSTOMER_NAME
        strCountStartDate = !COUNT_START_DATE
        strCCStatus = !CC_STATUS
        varData = Split(strMPG, "/") ' Get all comma delimited fields

        ' Update First Record
        .Edit
        !SPLIT_MPG = Trim(varData(0)) ' remove spaces before writing new fields
        .Update

        ' Add records with same first field
        ' and new fields for remaining data at end of string
        For i = 1 To UBound(varData)
            With rsADD
                .AddNew
                !MPG = strMPG
                !SPLIT_MPG = Trim(varData(i)) ' remove spaces before writing new fields
                !BUSINESS_NAME = strBusinessName
                !CUSTOMER_NUMBER = strCustomerNumber
                !CUSTOMER_NAME = strCustomerName
                !COUNT_START_DATE = strCountStartDate
                !CC_STATUS = strCCStatus
                .Update
            End With
        Next
        .MoveNext
    Wend

    .Close
    rsADD.Close

End With

Set rsADD = Nothing
Set rs = Nothing
db.Close
Set db = Nothing
```

End Sub

I can't post images yet due to reputation constrictions, but here are some links.

Here's the multiple after the code:
https://s9.postimg.org/fn3u70b5b/Multiple.jpg

Here's the single records after code run:
https://s10.postimg.org/bfq9z4snt/Singles.jpg

I feel like there's something super simple that I'm missing here, but it looks like I'm already taking the MPG over, so i'm curious as to why I'm not getting the singles or the first of the series. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: `tmStarCycleCountStatuses_SlashesforCommas` is a table, right? From the screenshots, there doesn't seem to be a primary key. Which is bad. This in combination with two recordsets operating on the same table might cause this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks right to me, except that you have to declare like this:

```
Dim strMPG As String
Dim strBusinessNames As String
Dim strCustomerNumbers As String
Dim strCustomerNames As String
Dim strCountStartDates As String
Dim strCCStatus As String
```

I guess you will have to insert some lines with `Debug.Print ..` to narrow down the happenings.

Comment: Splitting the declarations into separate lines has no effect.

Comment: No, that's what I thought. But still. Now, what could `Debug.Print` tell?

Comment: Same thing in my post. It's missing the first values.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Ended up changing my approach. This code will work. The pattern, regardless of length, would always be the same, so I used a Right/Left combo and integers

```
Public Sub ReformatmStarCycleCountStatusesTable()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strMPG As String
Dim strBusinessName As String
Dim strCustomerNumber As String
Dim strCustomerName As String
Dim dteCountStartDate As Date
Dim strCCStatus As String
Dim strSplitMPG As String
Dim intRemainingLength As Integer
Dim intInitialLength As Integer
Dim intStartPoint As Integer
Dim varData As Variant

Set db = CurrentDb
DoCmd.SetWarnings False

' Select all eligible fields (have a comma)
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [mStar Cycle Count Statuses] WHERE [PRODUCT_FILTER_VALUE] is not null"

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)
With rs
    While Not .EOF
        strMPG = !PRODUCT_FILTER_VALUE
        strBusinessName = !BUSINESS_NAME
        strCustomerNumber = !CUSTOMER_NUMBER
        dteCountStartDate = !COUNT_START_DATE
        strCCStatus = !Status

        intInitialLength = Len(strMPG)
        intRemainingLength = intInitialLength

        intStartPoint = 2

        Do While intRemainingLength > 0

            strSQL = "INSERT INTO tmStarCycleCountStatuses VALUES ('" & strBusinessName & "', '" & strCustomerNumber _
                   & "', #" & dteCountStartDate & "#, '" & strCCStatus & "', '" & Right(Left(strMPG, intStartPoint), 2) & "')"
            DoCmd.RunSQL (strSQL)

            intStartPoint = intStartPoint + 3
            intRemainingLength = intRemainingLength - 3

        Loop

        intStartPoint = 1
        .MoveNext

    Wend

    .Close

End With

DoCmd.SetWarnings True
Set rs = Nothing
db.Close
Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```